# How to detect fast click on object?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to detect fast click on button, and add a css class, which is "img-carousel-div-animation" on object if user clicks button fast (more than 1 click per 600ms). 
I tried setTimeout func, which removes class, but it didn't work, since it runs function anyway, but I need to run only if user doesn't click on button for 600ms. Here's the code I tried:

```
function slideLeft() {
if (isEnd == 0) {
    imgCarouselDiv.addClass('img-carousel-div-animation');
    animationTime = 100;
} else {
    imgCarouselDiv.removeClass('img-carousel-div-animation');
    animationTime = 540;
}
changeSlide(n, 0, 1);
n--;
}

function changeSlide(a, c, d) {
isEnd = 0;
setTimeout(function() {
    isEnd = 1;
}, 540);
//rest of function
...
}
```

Comment: Oh, I meant 540ms

Comment: Google for 'javascript debouncing' that's where you will find the answer

Answer (score 0):

Removing the class will not remove the click event from the element. You could check on each click if the element still has the class and then add the class back on the timeout.

Comment: Maybe something more specific?

Comment: There's this thing called Google that can find specific things for you if you ask nicely.

Comment: if google could help, I wouldn't wait for your answer here, trust me.

Comment: @bleatinterteiment really? Because google just helped me plenty when i asked it "javascript stop multiple clicks settimeout"... You must have not asked it nicely.

Answer (score 0):

This is called **debouncing**. David Walsh has [a very nice post about the subject](https://davidwalsh.name/javascript-debounce-function), and it works on a pretty simple way, that doesn't actually rely on jQuery.